# Button Link to Modal in Template - Relative URL

Tags: list, url, modal-dialog, template, links

Good Morning!~

I have a button on a page that brings up the modal newform for a Questions and Answers list.

javascript:

```
var options=SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();options.url='https://server/sites/collection/subsite/Lists/Questions Answers/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1';options.height = 400;void(SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options));
```

This works great...except it is on a template site.
We need the url to be relative or possibly dynamically update when a new template is created (thinking way outside my box here)?

I've tried /lists, ../../lists, etc....and I am sure I am missing something as A) it is not working...and B) in my mind there is nothing linking it to the list???

Your expertise and time is GREATLY appreciated!~

Answer (score 1):

For keeping the URL dynamic, you can use `_sppagecontextinfo`. Below is an example for your reference.

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/" + listTitle + "/NewForm.aspx";
```